# jQuery: display a text inside the parent div with an animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm on basic jQuery. I'd like to display a text inside a div with some kind of animation and give a white background to the same div. This is a starting code I made:

```
<div class="square square1">
    <p class="toggle">some text</p> 
</div>    
<div class="square square2"></div>
<div class="square square3"></div>
<div class="square square4"></div>
```

..the style..

```
.square {
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
.toggle {
display:none; 
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
```

..and the simple js.

```
$('.square1').click(function(){
   $('.toggle').slideToggle(300).addClass('white');
});
```

The problem is that I'm sure this is not the right way to display a text inside a container. The div is 'jumping' when the text is toggled.

Also, is there some jQuery animation to display a content with a 'nicer' movement? Toggle is so rude!

On fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2pnxf4go/9/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're after. Is this it http://jsfiddle.net/0mxu5bgf/?

Comment: I thought about absolute positioning, and it works for that. But my original divs are going to be inside a responsive layout and I can't play with absolute layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
var activeDIV = document.querySelector("div");

activeDIV.addEventListener("click", toggleMe, false);

function toggleMe(e) {
    this.classList.toggle("toggle")
}
```

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0}
.square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden
}

.square p{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align:center;
    background: current-color;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease, background .3s .3s ease; 
    -moz-transition: transform .3s ease, background .3s .3s ease; 
    transition: transform .3s ease, background .3s .3s ease 
}
.toggle p{
    background: white;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0%);
    transform: translateY(0%)
}
```

```html
<div class="square square1">
    <p class="toggle">some text</p> 
</div>    
<div class="square square2"></div>
<div class="square square3"></div>
<div class="square square4"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Tambo! Seems like a CSS master solution! I added a `transition-duration: 1s;` to make it smooth and I like it

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with out jquery animations and use css transitions instead.

```
$('.square1').click(function(){
    $('.toggle').addClass('white');
});
```

CSS:

```
.toggle{
    color: transparent;
    transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.toggle.white{
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: I need to see my text inside a white square. This is just hiding my text

Comment: I just changed the above code. You could also use opacity instead of color